# I cant figure out which selector is causing a text to reappear in my audio player in Chrome even though it works fine in firefox

Tags: html, css

Ok I created a player with soundmanager2. Now it plays and I customized it further but there is a problem I just cant seem to fix. When the user hovers over the player the text drops down but as soon as they leave the box and the music plays /pauses the text goes up again until I hover over the player. I cant figure out what is causing this in chrome as it works fine in firefox and ie.

here the page so you can have a better idea of what I mean: http://tinyurl.com/agvmueo

Now, Im not sure what to do and it really is frustrating me.

and here the CSS, just in case:

```
.ui360,
.sm2-360ui{position:relative}
.ui360,.sm2-360ui{min-width:50px;min-height:50px}
.sm2-360ui{width:50px;height:50px}
.ui360,.ui360 *{vertical-align:middle}
.sm2-360ui{position:relative;display:inline-block;float:left;display:inline}
.sm2-360ui.sm2_playing,.sm2-360ui.sm2_paused{z-index:10}
.ui360 a{float:left;display:inline;position:relative;color:#000;text-decoration:none;left:3px;top:18px;text-indent:50px}
.ui360 a.sm2_link{text-indent:0}
.ui360 a,.ui360 a:hover,.ui360 a:focus{padding:2px;margin-left:-2px;margin-top:-2px}
.ui360 a:hover,.ui360 a:focus{outline:none}
.ui360 .sm2-canvas{position:absolute;left:0;top:-15px}
.ui360 .sm2-timing{position:absolute;display:block;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;font:11px "helvetica neue",helvetica,monaco,lucida,terminal,monospace;color:#666;text-align:center;line-height:50px}
.ui360 .sm2-timing.aligntweak{text-indent:1px}
.ui360 .sm2-cover{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:2;display:none;background-image:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==)}
.ui360 .sm2-360btn{position:absolute;display:block;top:50%;left:50%;width:50px;height:50px;margin-left:-25px;margin-top:-25px;cursor:pointer;z-index:3}
.ui360 .sm2-360data{display:inline-block;font-family:helvetica}
.sm2-inline-block .ui360 .sm2-360btn,.ui360 .sm2-360ui.sm2_playing .sm2-360btn,.ui360 .sm2-360ui.sm2_paused .sm2-360btn{width:22px;height:22px;margin-left:-11px;margin-top:-11px}
.ui360 .sm2-360ui.sm2_playing .sm2-cover,.ui360 .sm2-360ui.sm2_paused .sm2-cover{display:block}
.ui360 .sm2-360ui.sm2_playing .sm2-timing{visibility:visible}
.ui360 .sm2-360ui.sm2_buffering .sm2-timing{visibility:hidden}
.ui360 .sm2-360ui .sm2-timing,.ui360 .sm2-360ui .sm2-360btn:hover + .sm2-timing,.ui360 .sm2-360ui.sm2_paused .sm2-timing{visibility:hidden}
.ui360 .sm2-360ui.sm2_dragging .sm2-timing,.ui360 .sm2-360ui.sm2_dragging .sm2-360btn:hover + .sm2-timing{/* paused + dragging */visibility:visible}
.ui360 .sm2-360ui.sm2_playing .sm2-360btn,.ui360 .sm2-360ui.sm2_dragging .sm2-360btn,.ui360 .sm2-360ui.sm2_dragging .sm2-360btn:hover,.ui360 .sm2-360ui.sm2_dragging .sm2-360btn-playing:hover{background:transparent;cursor:auto}
.ui360 .sm2-360ui.sm2_buffering .sm2-360btn,.ui360 .sm2-360ui.sm2_buffering .sm2-360btn:hover{background:transparent url(../images/icon_loading_dots.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;opacity:0.5;visibility:visible}
.sm2-inline-list .ui360,.sm2-inline-block .ui360{position:relative;display:inline-block;float:left;_display:inline;margin-bottom:-15px}
.sm2-inline-list .ui360{margin-right:-2px}
.sm2-inline-block .ui360{margin-right:8px}
.sm2-inline-list .ui360 a{display:none}
ul.ui360playlist{list-style-type:none}
ul.ui360playlist,ul.ui360playlist li{margin:0;padding:0}
div.ui360 div.metadata{display:none}
div.ui360 a span.metadata,div.ui360 a span.metadata *{vertical-align:baseline}
.ui360-vis,.ui360-vis .sm2-360ui,.sm2-inline-list .ui360-vis{width:180px;height:150px}
.ui360-vis{position:relative;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;margin-bottom:-18px;padding-left:248px;margin-left:0;background-position:22.6% 50%}
.sm2-inline-list .ui360-vis{cursor:pointer}
.ui360-vis a{font:14px "helvetica neue",helvetica,monaco,lucida,terminal,monospace;white-space:nowrap;text-indent:0;top:46%}
.sm2-inline-list .ui360-vis a{line-height:256px;top:auto}
.ui360-vis .sm2-360ui{margin-left:-256px}
.ui360-vis .sm2-timing{font:bold 24px "helvetica neue",helvetica,monaco,lucida,terminal,monospace;color:#333;text-align:center;line-height:150px;text-indent:0}
.sm2-inline-list .ui360-vis,.sm2-inline-list .ui360-vis .sm2-360ui{margin-left:0}
.sm2-inline-list .ui360-vis{transition:all 1s;-moz-transition:all 1s;-webkit-transition:all 1s;-o-transition:all 1s;border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;-moz-border-radius:15px;-webkit-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;-o-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;margin:10px;border:2px solid #e6e6e6;padding-left:0;background-position:50% 50%;overflow:hidden;behavior:url(PIE.htc);position:relative}
.sm2-inline-list .ui360-vis .sm2-360ui{margin-left:-1px;margin-top:-1px}
.sm2-inline-list .ui360-vis:hover{border-radius:100px 100px 100px 100px;-moz-border-radius:100px;-webkit-border-radius:100px 100px 100px 100px;-o-border-radius:100px 100px 100px 100px;overflow:hidden;behavior:url(PIE.htc);position:relative}
.sm2-inline-list .ui360-vis a{position:absolute;display:inline;left:0;bottom:0;top:1px;width:100%;height:100%;height:256px;overflow:hidden;transition:all 1s;color:#333;font-size:16px;margin:0;padding:0;line-height:250px;line-height:250px;text-align:center;transition:all 1s;-moz-transition:all 1s;-webkit-transition:all 1s;-o-transition:all 1s}
.sm2-inline-list .ui360 a:hover{background-color:transparent;line-height:800px;line-height:800px}
.sm2-inline-list .ui360-vis:hover .sm2-360ui,.sm2-inline-list .ui360-vis a.sm2_link:hover,.sm2-inline-list .ui360-vis a.sm2_link:active,.sm2-inline-list .ui360-vis a.sm2_link:focus{}
.sm2-inline-list .ui360-vis:hover a.sm2_link{line-height:800px;line-height:800px}
.ui360-vis .sm2-360btn,.ui360-vis .sm2-360ui.sm2_paused .sm2-360btn,.ui360-vis .sm2-360ui.sm2_playing .sm2-360btn{width:48px;height:48px;margin-left:-24px;margin-top:-24px}
.ui360-vis,.ui360-vis .sm2-360ui.sm2_paused .sm2-360btn,.ui360-vis .sm2-360btn-default{background:transparent url(../images/360-button-vis-play.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,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);background-image:url(../images/360-button-vis-play.png);_background:transparent url(../images/360-button-vis-play.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;cursor:pointer}
.ui360-vis:hover .sm2-360btn,.ui360-vis .sm2-360btn-default:hover,.ui360-vis .sm2-360ui.sm2_paused .sm2-360btn:hover{background:transparent url(../images/360-button-vis-play-light.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;_background:transparent url(../images/360-button-vis-play.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;cursor:pointer}
.ui360-vis .sm2-360ui.sm2_playing .sm2-360btn:hover,.ui360-vis .sm2-360btn-playing:hover{background:transparent url(../images/360-button-vis-pause-light.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;_background:transparent url(../images/360-button-vis-pause-light.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;cursor:pointer}
.ui360-vis{background-position:21% 50%;_background:transparent url(../images/360-button-vis-play.gif) no-repeat 21% 50%}
.ui360-vis .sm2-360btn-default{_background:transparent url(../images/360-button-vis-play.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%}
.ui360-vis .sm2-360ui.sm2_dragging .sm2-360btn{visibility:hidden}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of your css, it's because of your javascript. The text is supposed to do that because it disappears on hover, and it returns to it's default state when you are not hovering. And it happens in Firefox also.
What you have to do is `display: none` on the `<a href="#">Text</a>` when the user plays the audio, and `display: block` when it stops.